# Linq to Sql: How to quickly clear a table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, delete-row

To delete all the rows in a table, I am currently doing the following:

```
context.Entities.DeleteAllOnSubmit(context.Entities);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

However, this seems to be taking ages. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Any reason you are not using a Stored proc for faster and safer deletion? You can have the proc mapped onto dbml

Comment: Wouldn't you have to make one for each table then? Or?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You could do a normal SQL truncate or delete command, using the [DataContext.ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) method:

```
context.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM Entity");
```

Or

```
context.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Entity");
```

The way you are deleting is taking long because Linq to SQL generates a DELETE statement for **each entity**, there are other *type-safe* approaches to do batch deletes/updates, check the following articles:

- [Batch Updates and Deletes with LINQ to SQL](https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/)
- [LINQ to SQL Extension: Batch Deletion with Lambda Expression](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/archive/2008/03/06/linq-to-sql-extension-batch-deletion-by-lambda-expression.aspx)

Comment: make sure to fix the word "DELETE"

Comment: I +1'd this.  Here's a reference explaining the difference between Truncate (which I think you want to do), and Delete:
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1080

Comment: +1 on David's comment: truncate may be *a lot* faster than delete

Comment: actually you might have to worry about this as well:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e21ec1b7-4468-4a37-84e1-3d6a79e58c6b

Comment: @David: That problem is specific to the Entity Framework (*Linq-to-Entities*), I have used `TRUNCATE` before without problems on Linq-to-SQL

Comment: How would you use Truncate? `context.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE Entity");`, or something?

Comment: CMS, yeah, I just caught that (I use EF now).  In EF you can use something like _db.DeleteObject(obj); for *one* obj.

Comment: marc_s is right, here's the full grammar:
TRUNCATE TABLE 
    [ { database_name.[ schema_name ]. | schema_name . } ]
    table_name
[ ; ]

Comment: Cool. Guess I will create a truncate extension method then :)

Comment: Truncate requires more rights than the normal writer rights required for a DELETE :)

Comment: TRUNCATE will clear out any auto indexing that has been established (typically an Id column) so be careful if you do not want that to reset.  DELETE FROM will not.

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately LINQ-to-SQL doesn't execute set based queries very well.

You would assume that

```
context.Entities.DeleteAllOnSubmit(context.Entities); 
context.SubmitChanges();
```

will translate to something like

```
DELETE FROM [Entities]
```

but unfortunately it's more like

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entities] WHERE ([EntitiesId] = @p0) AND ([Column1] = @p1) ...
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entities] WHERE ([EntitiesId] = @p0) AND ([Column1] = @p1) ...
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entities] WHERE ([EntitiesId] = @p0) AND ([Column1] = @p1) ...
```

You'll find the same when you try to do bulk update in LINQ-to-SQL. Any more than a few hundred rows at a time and it's simply going to be too slow.

If you need to do batch operations & you're using LINQ-to-SQL, you need to write stored procedures.

Answer (score 13):

I like using an Extension Method, per the following:

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
  public static void Truncate<TEntity>(this Table<TEntity> table) where TEntity : class
  {
    var rowType = table.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var tableName = table.Context.Mapping.GetTable(rowType).TableName;
    var sqlCommand = String.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE {0}", tableName);
    table.Context.ExecuteCommand(sqlCommand);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use this:

```
Public void BorraFilasTabla()
{
 using(basededatos db = new basededatos())
 {
  var ListaParaBorrar = db.Tabla.Tolist();
  db.Tabla.RemoveRange(ListaParaBorrar); 
 }
}
```

Comment: The question is: "Is there a faster way?". How would this be faster? Also, this is not LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score -1):

The Below c# code is used to Insert/Update/Delete/DeleteAll on a database table using LINQ to SQL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace PracticeApp
{
    class PracticeApp
    {        
        public void InsertRecord(string Name, string Dept) {
            LinqToSQLDataContext LTDT = new LinqToSQLDataContext();
            LINQTOSQL0 L0 = new LINQTOSQL0 { NAME = Name, DEPARTMENT = Dept };
            LTDT.LINQTOSQL0s.InsertOnSubmit(L0);
            LTDT.SubmitChanges();
        }

        public void UpdateRecord(int ID, string Name, string Dept)
        {
            LinqToSQLDataContext LTDT = new LinqToSQLDataContext();
            LINQTOSQL0 L0 = (from item in LTDT.LINQTOSQL0s where item.ID == ID select item).FirstOrDefault();
            L0.NAME = Name;
            L0.DEPARTMENT = Dept;
            LTDT.SubmitChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteRecord(int ID)
        {
            LinqToSQLDataContext LTDT = new LinqToSQLDataContext();
            LINQTOSQL0 L0;
            if (ID != 0)
            {
                L0 = (from item in LTDT.LINQTOSQL0s where item.ID == ID select item).FirstOrDefault();
                LTDT.LINQTOSQL0s.DeleteOnSubmit(L0);
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable<LINQTOSQL0> Data = from item in LTDT.LINQTOSQL0s where item.ID !=0 select item;
                LTDT.LINQTOSQL0s.DeleteAllOnSubmit(Data);
            }           
            LTDT.SubmitChanges();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.Write("* Enter Comma Separated Values to Insert Records\n* To Delete a Record Enter 'Delete' or To Update the Record Enter 'Update' Then Enter the Values\n* Dont Pass ID While Inserting Record.\n* To Delete All Records Pass 0 as Parameter for Delete.\n");
            var message = "Successfully Completed";
            try
            {
                PracticeApp pa = new PracticeApp();
                var enteredValue = Console.ReadLine();                
                if (Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[0] == "Delete") 
                {
                    Console.Write("Delete Operation in Progress...\n");
                    pa.DeleteRecord(Int32.Parse(Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[1]));
                }
                else if (Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[0] == "Update")
                {
                    Console.Write("Update Operation in Progress...\n");
                    pa.UpdateRecord(Int32.Parse(Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[1]), Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[2], Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[3]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Insert Operation in Progress...\n");
                    pa.InsertRecord(Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[0], Regex.Split(enteredValue, ",")[1]);
                }                                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = ex.ToString();
            }
            Console.Write(message);            
            Console.ReadLine();                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add some explanation