# Delete table in ef 4 - mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I tries to delete an entity - table

This is the code:

```
db.Sessions.SqlQuery("delete table session");
db.SaveChanges();
```

This isnt delete the table. Or do anything..
db is inherits from DbContext object.

I've found a solution

```
foreach (var item in db.Sessions)
{
    db.Sessions.Remove(item);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

But I'm sure theres a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlQuery` as the name implies only for executing queries if you want to drop the table you need something else:

With the use of the [DbContext.Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database%28v=vs.103%29) property you can execute any DDL/DML query:

```
db.DataBase.ExecuteSqlCommand("drop table sessions");
```

I have also created a repro and it's working fine with EF4.3.1 with SQL Server2008:

```
using (var db = new EFRepros())
{
    db.Sessions.Add(new Session() { Name = "Test1" });
    db.Sessions.Add(new Session() { Name = "Test2" });
    db.Sessions.Add(new Session() { Name = "Test3" });
    db.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine(db.Sessions.Count()); // Output: 3
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from sessions");
    //db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table sessions"); //this also works
    Console.WriteLine(db.Sessions.Count()); // Output: 0
}
```

Note: EF by default use plurar table names so you need to use **sessions**.

Comment: I dont want to drop. I want to delete/truncate. And when I tries it, it returns: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = truncate ]"

Comment: Have you tried `db.DataBase.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM session");`?

Comment: @nir I've updated my answer, for me both delete and truncate works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to drop the table?  If so, you can't do that through a `SqlQuery` call because, as the name implies, that method deals strictly with querying.

If you're trying to delete all the rows from a table, then this question is a duplicate of this:

[Linq to Sql: How to quickly clear a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516962/linq-to-sql-how-to-clear-a-table-fast)